# Firefox getComputedStyle returns "auto"

Tags: javascript, firefox

This question has been asked before about the "height" and "width" properties but I found no working solution.

[Firefox documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) says:

> In Firefox, properties with the value `auto` return the used value, not the value `auto`.

However, `window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("top")` returns `"auto"` instead of the pixel value. Does anybody know a workaround?

Firefox 42.0 on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Don't use the non-standard getComputedStyle? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element

Comment: Pretty standard in 2015, I would think. Firefox on Windows 7 returns `0px`.

Comment: It returns `auto` on FF 43, Arch.

Comment: @JacqueGoupil http://caniuse.com/#search=getcomputedstyle

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Thanks, `element.getBoundingClientRect()` was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't know that `getComputedStyle` is non-standard though.

Comment: Well, getComputedStyle is somewhat standard, but it doesn't return consistent values based on which browser you're using, especially for colors (hex, rgb components, name?) and dimensions once you start using percentages and the css `calc` function. It's worst when you've got scrollbars - some browsers include the scrollbar's width and some don't. You're better off with getBoundingClientRect.

Comment: Bounding box is no longer a viable answer for all scenarios. getComputedStyle allows the return of psuedo element styles....somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your element has `position: static`. Any other type of positioning seems to be computed correctly. Here's a test for a static element:

```js
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element')).top;
```

```css
#element {
  top : auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Here's another one for `position: relative`:

```js
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element')).top;
```

```css
#element {
  position: relative;
  top : auto;
  }
```

```html
<div id="element"></div>
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

`top` should be a no op for `static` elements. So it might be better to use the Rect methods instead in that case.

Comment: This fix does not work in ie. Worth mentioning. Clever find though.